# regex to grab 2 strings from line

Tags: c#, regex

is this the correct way to handle this?

```
string item = "strawb bana  .93";

string itemPattern = @"\w*";
string pricePattern = @"\d*\.\d*";

var match = Regex.Match(item, itemPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var match2 = Regex.Match(item, pricePattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

if (match.Success & match2.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine("match");
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
    Console.WriteLine(match2.Value);
}
else
    Console.WriteLine("no match");
```

is there a more concise way perhaps? Actually, I'm not grabbing the item correctly. Basically, I want to grab the item and price.

Comment: Please post a sample of the file you are trying to parse. Without it, it is hard to determine whether the regular expressions are correct.

Comment: can your item contain digits eg "lager 6 pack"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
[\w\s]*\d*\.\d*
```

and by using `Grouping constructs`, your code should be like this:

```
string item = "strawb bana  .93";

foreach(Match match in Regex.Matches(item, @"(?<str>[\w\s]*)(?<num>\d*\.\d+)"))
{
    String str = match.Groups["str"].Value;
    String nuum = match.Groups["num"].Value;
}
```

explain:

**`(?< name > subexpression)`**
Captures the matched subexpression into a named group.

Comment: again, since \w matches alphanumerics, the \w\s character class will eat into any preceding digits on the price. This pattern might work for .93, but it won't work for a price over one dollar (1.93).

Comment: it would also match a line containing a single dot due to the * operator, and would also match a price with endless decimals 3.1415926 etc., not a valid dollar amount.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the line to this and it should match your item even if it contains spaces:

`string itemPattern = @"[a-z\s]*";`

**UPDATE:** *A better approach is to use **groups**:*

```
        string item = "strawb bana as .93";
        string itemPattern = @"([a-z\s]*)(\d*\.*\d*)";
        var match = Regex.Match(item, itemPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        if (match.Success)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("match");
            Console.WriteLine("name: "+match.Groups[1].Value);
            Console.WriteLine("Price: "+match.Groups[2].Value);
        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine("no match");
        Console.Read();
```

Comment: [\w\s]* would also match pricePattern

Comment: \w matches alphanumerics, so wouldn't match correctly in the case of "item 3.45"

Comment: no need of `A-Z` since you are using `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`

Comment: also, the * can match nothing - this regex would match a line containing a single '.' (the '+', one or more, would be better here I'd think)

Answer (score 1):

```
([a-zA-Z\s]+).*?(\d*\.\d{2})  //item in group 1, price in group 2
```

*case insensitive, matches prices of .93 or 11.93 (digits preceding decimals are optional), also will match a slighter weirder string like "Strawb bana-11.98"

*updated: to match items with numbers in them:*

```
([\w\s]+?).?(\d*\.\d{2}) //matches 'item42 Bananas .55'
```

(clearly you can keep dreaming up inputs and making the pattern progressively more complicated, but maybe I should just go to bed :)

Comment: what if it were "item42 Bananas 4 5.55" - 4 is qty purchased and 5.55 would be the price. and item42 Bananas would be desc?

Comment: I think something like this would work: ([\w\s]+?)(\s\d+?)?\s(\d*\.\d{2})
Now you have three groups with the middle one being the quantity. (assumes space is the delimiter)

Answer (score 0):

You likely want to combine to one regex and use grouping to capture the parts you want (check my C# as I'm not a C# developer!)

```
string item = "strawb bana .93";
string pattern = @"([a-z\s]+)(\d*\.\d{2})"
var match = Regex.Match(item,pattern,RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

if( match.Success ) {
    item_name = match.Groups[1].value;
    price = match.Groups[2].value;
}
```

As for the regex itself:

`([a-z\s]+)` matches one or more (the + sign) letters or spaces and captures them as group 1

`(\d*\.` starts group two and optionally matches one or more numbers followed by a period

`\d{2})` matches exactly two digits and closes the second group

**Edit**: There seems to be some disagreement about how `?` is interpreted by C#. I've changed `\d+?` to `\d*` which means "0 or more digits"

Comment: fails on the given input string due to \d+? which must match one or more digits.

Comment: @sweaver2112 not true `?` makes it optional

Comment: from msdn: Matches the previous element one or more times, but as few times as possible.

Comment: @sweaver2112 another site I found said that C# uses PCRE in which case the `?` should make the match optional. But since there is ambiguity I'll change it to `\d*`